# Second opinion: circuit for camping van

Tags: circuit-design, battery-charging, design, fuses, review

I am customizing a van to take on a camping trip and want to install some electrical applications. With only little experience on this topic I did my research online and drew up a schematic for the following circuit:

[image]

A bit of information about my design and expectations:

- I'll use an 100 Ah battery to supply power for my applications (a different battery for the starter motor is already in place).
- The battery will be charged by solar power and the dynamo (already in place for the starter battery).
- An intelligent battery combiner will be used to prioritize the starter battery when charging by dynamo and keep it from draining when anything else but the starter motor is used.
- A converter(12 V DC to 230 V AC) for charging my laptop and photocamera.
- Fuses will be used for protection against damage from a short-circuit.

Now I would like to have some feedback on this design. Some specific questions that I have:

1. Are the fuses placed between the dynamo and battery correct? Research showed that it is questionable to put them there at all. And if I do place them, where would I place them and which size should they be?
2. For the mainline towards my 12 V applications I have 30 A mainfuse. Then for all my applications I have a separate fuse. Is this double protection necessary? If not, should I use the main fuse or sepsrate fuses for all applications?
3. What is the best way to prevent the battery from discharging to a point where it becomes damaged?
4. Is there anything specific I should look out for when grounding? Is connecting the two zero poles from both battery's sufficient?

If there is anything else out of the ordinary I would be more than happy to know.

Comment: That's a block diagram with some information on it. A schematic is far more detailed (and probably needed to answer all your questions).

Comment: FYI, A common English name for the battery that supplies power to lighting and appliances in a recreational vehicle or in a boat is, "house battery."

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to prevent the battery from discharging to a point where it becomes damaged?

Is this the solar battery charger shown in your diagram? https://www.victronenergy.com/solar-charge-controllers/mppt-100-30 It appears to have only two ports; one for the solar panel, and one for the battery.  Some similar chargers also have a "load" port. If you had a three-port charger, and if you connected everything that draws power from the house battery to the "load" port, then you could rely on the charger to switch off the "load" when the battery voltage dropped below some safe threshold (maybe configurable, probably somewhere close to 11V.)

You might also consider shopping for purpose-built "battery management systems" that are intended for use in recreational vehicles.

Comment: I would say that a battery manager is the way to go. On my aux battery system I went with a RedArc BCDC system, there are plenty others. They will isolate your aux battery from your start battery, prioritize solar charging with its own MPPT over alternator for charging,

Comment: Thank you for your input! The battery manager seems like a good option for me but I can't find right one for me that has shipping to my house. The mppt with the extra load ports should suffice aswell. Ill be going with this